# Pipe an output into echo as an variable for calculation

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, pipe, echo

My goal is to divide 2 text files, each containing a single integer,
but limiting the answer to 2 decimal places.

I managed to do it with `paste total.txt count.txt | awk '{printf "%.2f\n", $1/$2}'`

But I saw another way of using `echo 'scale=2; <calculation here>' | bc -l`

I couldn't figure out how to pass the numbers from the previous pipe to `echo` as an variable/argument, I tried use `xargs` but didn't know how to reference it.

I tried this: `paste -d/ total.txt count.txt | bc -l | xargs echo 'scale=2;' | bc -l`
and this: `echo 'scale=2; $(paste -d/ total.txt count.txt)/1' | bc -l`

My goal is to pipe output into `echo` as a variable for calculation or use commands inside `echo` , thank you.

Comment: `echo` does not process stdin. Consequentially you can't _pipe_ anything into it. The best you can do is to pass something to `echo` as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
total.txt = 100    
count.txt = 3
```

```
bc <<< "scale=2; $(paste -d '/' total.txt count.txt);"
33.33
```

or

```
echo "scale=2; $(paste -d '/' total.txt count.txt);" | bc -l
33.33
```

Your attempt:

```
echo 'scale=2; $(paste -d/ total.txt count.txt)/1' | bc -l
```

was close, but with single quotes, you prevent the shell to expand the `$(command substitution)`.

---

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, I got it working now with double quotes. And yes, I will need to look into the quotation for linux.